# Trouble with memoir documentclass, blank pages

Tags: memoir, blank-page

I am currently writing my master thesis. Got a template, it seems rather old but still working. One thing really bothers me:

I can not get a single blank page after the title page. All I can do is no blank page or double blank page. If I print the thesis, pages that should be on the left are on the right and vice versa. Also page indention is different for left and right pages (`memoir`).

Can you help me get a single blank page after the title page and before the abstract?

The template is quite huge. Didnt know which lines really belong to a "minimum" WE. However, I have a tested MWE with the same issue:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oldfontcommands,twoside, fleqn,openright]{memoir}%makeidx

\input{style.tex}

\hypersetup
{
pdftitle = {},
pdfsubject = {},
pdfauthor = {},
pdfkeywords = {}
}

\renewcommand{\chapterautorefname}{Kapitel}
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Kapitel}
\renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Abbildung}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\pagestyle{empty}
This is actually the first page of the thesis and will be discarded after the print out. This is done because 
the title page has to be an even page. The memoir style package used by this template makes different indentations 
for odd and even pages which is usally done for better readability.  
\clearpage

\pagestyle{empty}
\rmfamily
\noindent
\begin{center}
University of \\
Faculty of  \\
Science of \\
\end{center}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
%\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{pictures/logo.pdf}
\end{figure}
\vfill\vfill
\begin{center}
\Large
\textbf{ Thesis}\\
\end{center}
\vspace{2.0em}
\begin{center}
\Large
\Large Title of Thesis
\end{center}
\vspace{2.0em}
\begin{center}
    \normalsize
    submitted by\\
    \large
    Name of Author\\
    \normalsize
    Date
\end{center}
\vspace{2.0em}
\begin{center}
    \normalsize
    CorrectorName01:\\

\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \normalsize
    CorrectorName02:\\

\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \normalsize
     name1  \\
     name2
   \hspace{2mm}  


\end{center}


\cleardoublepage

\chapter*{Abstract}

content of abstract

\chapter*{Acknowledgments}

\backmatter

\end{document}
```

and the contents of style.tex

```
%******************************************************************************
% PACKAGES
%******************************************************************************
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{ifsym}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{cite}


%******************************************************************************
% INDEX GENERATION
%******************************************************************************
\makeindex

%******************************************************************************
% HYPEREF/ALGORITHM FIX
%******************************************************************************
\newcommand{\theHalgorithm}{\arabic{algorithm}}

%******************************************************************************
% NUMBERING
%******************************************************************************
\numberwithin{algorithm}{chapter}
\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}

%******************************************************************************
% PAGE NUMBER IN BIBLIOGRAPHY
%******************************************************************************
\usepackage{citeref}
\renewcommand{\bibitempages}[1]{\newblock {\scriptsize [\mbox{zitiert auf S.\ }#1]}}

%******************************************************************************
% PDF HYPERLINKS
%******************************************************************************
\ifpdf
  \pdfcompresslevel=9
        \usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,bookmarksnumbered,%
        colorlinks=true,%
        linkcolor=blue,%
        citecolor=blue,%
        filecolor=blue,%
        pagecolor=blue,%
        urlcolor=blue,%
        pdftex,
        unicode]{hyperref} 
    \input supp-mis.tex
    \input supp-pdf.tex
    \pdfimageresolution=600
    \usepackage{thumbpdf} 
\else
    \usepackage{hyperref}
\fi
\usepackage{memhfixc}


\newcolumntype{H}[1]{>{\columncolor[gray]{0.90}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{I}[1]{>{\centering\columncolor[gray]{0.90}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{q}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
%******************************************************************************
% CHAPTER AND SECTION STYLE
%******************************************************************************
\makechapterstyle{mychapterstyle}{%
    \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}%
    \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}%
    \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}%
    \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
        \chaptitlefont\hrule height 0.5pt \vspace{1em}%
        {##1}\vspace{1em}\hrule height 0.5pt%
        }%
    \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{%
        \chapnumfont\thechapter%
        }%
}
\chapterstyle{mychapterstyle}
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\sffamily\bfseries}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\setparaheadstyle{\normalfont\sffamily}
\makeevenhead{headings}{\thepage}{}{\small\slshape\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\small\slshape\rightmark}{}{\thepage}

%******************************************************************************
% TABLE OF CONTENTS STYLE
%******************************************************************************
\settocdepth{subsection}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsection}
\settocdepth{subsection}
\maxtocdepth{subsection}

%******************************************************************************
% COMMANDS FOR EPIGRAPHS
%******************************************************************************
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.57\textwidth}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\setlength{\beforeepigraphskip}{1\baselineskip}
\setlength{\afterepigraphskip}{2\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\epitext}{\sffamily\itshape}
\newcommand{\epiauthor}{\sffamily\scshape ---~}
\newcommand{\epititle}{\sffamily\itshape}
\newcommand{\epidate}{\sffamily\scshape}
\newcommand{\episkip}{\medskip}
\newcommand{\myepigraph}[4]{%
    \epigraph{\epitext #1\episkip}{\epiauthor #2\\\epititle #3 \epidate(#4)}\noindent}


%******************************************************************************
% FOOTNOTE STYLE
%******************************************************************************
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

%******************************************************************************
% COLORS
%******************************************************************************
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{greenyellow}   {cmyk}{0.15, 0   , 0.69, 0   }
\definecolor{yellow}        {cmyk}{0   , 0   , 1   , 0   }
\definecolor{goldenrod}     {cmyk}{0   , 0.10, 0.84, 0   }
\definecolor{dandelion}     {cmyk}{0   , 0.29, 0.84, 0   }
\definecolor{apricot}       {cmyk}{0   , 0.32, 0.52, 0   }
\definecolor{peach}         {cmyk}{0   , 0.50, 0.70, 0   }
\definecolor{melon}         {cmyk}{0   , 0.46, 0.50, 0   }
\definecolor{yelloworange}  {cmyk}{0   , 0.42, 1   , 0   }
\definecolor{orange}        {cmyk}{0   , 0.61, 0.87, 0   }
\definecolor{burntorange}   {cmyk}{0   , 0.51, 1   , 0   }
\definecolor{bittersweet}   {cmyk}{0   , 0.75, 1   , 0.24}
\definecolor{redorange}     {cmyk}{0   , 0.77, 0.87, 0   }
\definecolor{mahogany}      {cmyk}{0   , 0.85, 0.87, 0.35}
\definecolor{maroon}        {cmyk}{0   , 0.87, 0.68, 0.32}
\definecolor{brickred}      {cmyk}{0   , 0.89, 0.94, 0.28}
\definecolor{red}           {cmyk}{0   , 1   , 1   , 0   }
\definecolor{orangered}     {cmyk}{0   , 1   , 0.50, 0   }
\definecolor{rubinered}     {cmyk}{0   , 1   , 0.13, 0   }
\definecolor{wildstrawberry}{cmyk}{0   , 0.96, 0.39, 0   }
\definecolor{salmon}        {cmyk}{0   , 0.53, 0.38, 0   }
\definecolor{carnationpink} {cmyk}{0   , 0.63, 0   , 0   }
\definecolor{magenta}       {cmyk}{0   , 1   , 0   , 0   }
\definecolor{violetred}     {cmyk}{0   , 0.81, 0   , 0   }
\definecolor{rhodamine}     {cmyk}{0   , 0.82, 0   , 0   }
\definecolor{mulberry}      {cmyk}{0.34, 0.90, 0   , 0.02}
\definecolor{redviolet}     {cmyk}{0.07, 0.90, 0   , 0.34}
\definecolor{fuchsia}       {cmyk}{0.47, 0.91, 0   , 0.08}
\definecolor{lavender}      {cmyk}{0   , 0.48, 0   , 0   }
\definecolor{thistle}       {cmyk}{0.12, 0.59, 0   , 0   }
\definecolor{orchid}        {cmyk}{0.32, 0.64, 0   , 0   }
\definecolor{darkorchid}    {cmyk}{0.40, 0.80, 0.20, 0   }
\definecolor{purple}        {cmyk}{0.45, 0.86, 0   , 0   }
\definecolor{plum}          {cmyk}{0.50, 1   , 0   , 0   }
\definecolor{violet}        {cmyk}{0.79, 0.88, 0   , 0   }
\definecolor{royalpurple}   {cmyk}{0.75, 0.90, 0   , 0   }
\definecolor{blueviolet}    {cmyk}{0.86, 0.91, 0   , 0.04}
\definecolor{periwinkle}    {cmyk}{0.57, 0.55, 0   , 0   }
\definecolor{cadetblue}     {cmyk}{0.62, 0.57, 0.23, 0   }
\definecolor{cornflowerblue}{cmyk}{0.65, 0.13, 0   , 0   }
\definecolor{midnightblue}  {cmyk}{0.98, 0.13, 0   , 0.43}
\definecolor{navyblue}      {cmyk}{0.94, 0.54, 0   , 0   }
\definecolor{royalblue}     {cmyk}{1   , 0.50, 0   , 0   }
\definecolor{blue}          {cmyk}{1   , 1   , 0   , 0   }
\definecolor{cerulean}      {cmyk}{0.94, 0.11, 0   , 0   }
\definecolor{cyan}          {cmyk}{1   , 0   , 0   , 0   }
\definecolor{processblue}   {cmyk}{0.96, 0   , 0   , 0   }
\definecolor{skyblue}       {cmyk}{0.62, 0   , 0.12, 0   }
\definecolor{turquoise}     {cmyk}{0.85, 0   , 0.20, 0   }
\definecolor{tealblue}      {cmyk}{0.86, 0   , 0.34, 0.02}
\definecolor{aquamarine}    {cmyk}{0.82, 0   , 0.30, 0   }
\definecolor{bluegreen}     {cmyk}{0.85, 0   , 0.33, 0   }
\definecolor{emerald}       {cmyk}{1   , 0   , 0.50, 0   }
\definecolor{junglegreen}   {cmyk}{0.99, 0   , 0.52, 0   }
\definecolor{seagreen}      {cmyk}{0.69, 0   , 0.50, 0   }
\definecolor{green}         {cmyk}{1   , 0   , 1   , 0   }
\definecolor{forestgreen}   {cmyk}{0.91, 0   , 0.88, 0.12}
\definecolor{pinegreen}     {cmyk}{0.92, 0   , 0.59, 0.25}
\definecolor{limegreen}     {cmyk}{0.50, 0   , 1   , 0   }
\definecolor{yellowgreen}   {cmyk}{0.44, 0   , 0.74, 0   }
\definecolor{springgreen}   {cmyk}{0.26, 0   , 0.76, 0   }
\definecolor{olivegreen}    {cmyk}{0.64, 0   , 0.95, 0.40}
\definecolor{rawsienna}     {cmyk}{0   , 0.72, 1   , 0.45}
\definecolor{sepia}         {cmyk}{0   , 0.83, 1   , 0.70}
\definecolor{brown}         {cmyk}{0   , 0.81, 1   , 0.60}
\definecolor{tan}           {cmyk}{0.14, 0.42, 0.56, 0   }
\definecolor{gray}          {cmyk}{0   , 0   , 0   , 0.50}
\definecolor{black}         {cmyk}{0   , 0   , 0   , 1   }
\definecolor{white}         {cmyk}{0   , 0   , 0   , 0   } 
\definecolor{cell}          {cmyk}{0   , 0   , 0   , 0.25} 
\definecolor{stahlblau}       {rgb} {0.2,0.56,0.84}
\definecolor{graurot}       {rgb} {0.62,0.15,0.15}
\definecolor{schwarz}       {rgb} {0.0,0.0,0.0}
```

Comment: It is uncommon that title of thesis is on even page. see if you replavce the firs `\clearpage` before thesis title with `\cleardoublepage` gives what you like to have. and of course: welcome to TeX.SE

Comment: Thank you Zarko. This results in this : First Page with "This is actually the first page...."; Blank Second Page; Titlepage on third page; Blank Fourth Page; Blank Fifth Page; Blank Sixth Page; Abstract on Seventh Page; Blank Eigth Page;... better but a lot of useless blank pages isnt it?

Comment: Well, this is intentional. All thesis which I read/supervised has such structure. when you start with core of your thesis, only chapter start on odd pages. If your tutor/university agree, you can change this with option `openany` (for memoir) and replace all `\doubleclearpage` with `\clearpage` , but then don't complain for missing empty pages :-). To my and many others taste (who design thesis templates) this lead to ugly result ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified Title page up to the Abstract which inserts a blank page between the two:

```
\frontmatter

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begingroup
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    University of \\
    Faculty of \\
    Science of \\
  \end{tabular}

  \vfill

  \includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image}% logo

  \vfill

  {\Large\bfseries Thesis}

  \vspace{2em}

  {\Large Title of Thesis}

  \vspace{2em}

  {\normalsize submitted by

   \large Name of Author

   \normalsize Date}

  \vspace{2em}

  {\normalsize CorrectorName01:

   \smallskip

   CorrectorName02: }

  \vspace{2em}

  {\normalsize name1

   name2}

\endgroup

\clearpage

% ==== INSERT A BLANK PAGE

\thispagestyle{empty}\mbox{}

\clearpage

% ==== MAKE SURE THIS STARTS ON AN ODD PAGE

\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter*{Abstract}
```

Since you're using `twoside` mode, `\cleardoublepage` will clear pages until it arrives at a recto (odd-numbered) page. However, since you've inserted a "please remove this page" *first* page, the Abstract will necessarily fall on an odd page.

The way around this is to force a blank page

```
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}\mbox{}
\clearpage
```

and also force the following page to start on an odd number

```
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

Since there's not official title entries used in the title page, there should not be a problem if you were to use [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

Comment: Thank you Werner, the blank pages are in the right positions!! There is one minor problem: The Abstract Page appears on the right, but the page indent is that from a left page (empty space on the right side is greater than the empty space on the left side). Is there a way to fix that too?

Comment: @Phtevenz: Try moving the `\setcounter{page}{1}` to before the `\clearpage` - on the blank page - and change it to `\setcounter{page}{0}`.

Comment: it is now % ==== INSERT A BLANK PAGE

\thispagestyle{empty}\mbox{}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\clearpage

Comment: sorry. how to edit here? it is now like above but no change

Comment: @Phtevenz: I don't see a problem with the output. Is this just from your viewer? I have odd pages (even in the `\frontmatter` where the Abstract and Acknowledgements are) showing an "open right" layout. That is, small gutter (inner) margin, big outer margin.

Comment: It looks the same on another pdf viewer. Also recompiled it on another machine with also another pdf viewer, still looks the same. But i am very glad the pages are right now